# How to disable "device mapper" warnings in fedora

Tags: linux, device-mapper, fedora-23

Mine is an x86 based embedded platform.. Running completely out of NFS. I recently ported fc23 onto it... But been getting this warning message every time I give the reboot command..

```
[  OK  ] Stopped Login Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Bring up/down networking.
         Stopping SYSV: Init script for live imag[ 1660.087787] watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes
device-mapper: remove ioctl on No failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on devices failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on found failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on No failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on devices failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on found failed: No such device or address
Command failed
device-mapper: remove ioctl on No failed: No such device or address
Command failed ...
```

(and so on for several seconds)
Though it reboots and works properly after that, it is annoying.. Is there a way to disable device-mapper if it is not being used?

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmsetup status
No devices found
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Does that mean device_mapper is not used and can be disabled? I am not sure what other details i need to provide here.. (Fairly new to linux..)